# Svelte behaviour with PReact (or other frameworks)

Tags: javascript, svelte, preact

If I import a JavaScript package which uses PReact or other frameworks in my Svelte project, will Svelte compile it?

Will Svelte compile the PReact framework and the package using it? This *should* not lead to any performance issue or size issue for that matter, as PReact is small and Svelte will compile it.

But my question is still, will Svelte compile the PReact framework when I use it in my Svelte project? Because if so is it better to exclude it (not compile it) or just not care? I am wondering for best practices.

EDIT:

I'm importing FullCalendar which is a preact app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Svelte is a compiler in the sense that it takes `.svelte` files and turn them into `.js` (conceptually at least). After you've run the compiler, via bundler plugin or otherwise (e.g. directly through the compiler API), you end up with JS code that doesn't rely on a full-fledged runtime to be executed (we could call that "low level" JS from a framework perspective).

Said otherwise: Svelte's compilation is focused solely on transforming Svelte syntax (as found in `.svelte` files) into "raw" Javascript.

Svelte compiler has no notion of the rest of your code, outside of `.svelte` files -- for example, what comes from `.js` files in your codebase or, pertaining to your question, what comes from other libs like Preact. From the point of view of the compiler, they are just imports from the outside and, in the end, they are just variables in the Svelte code.

So the answer to your question is: no, Svelte won't compile Preact or anything that is not Svelte syntax.

Resolving external imports would be a problematic of your browser (if using raw ES imports) or, more typically, of your bundler (e.g. Rollup, Webpack...). It is the bundler that will read your import statements, try to resolve them in your `node_modules`, rewrite everything to play together, optionally apply some code transformations (like transforming TS, SCSS or Svelte to raw JS), optimize them, pack them together for optimal performance, etc. Svelte changes nothing in this regard.

As a more personal opinion, it doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to use Preact in Svelte. You essentially have everything you'd have in Preact already in Svelte. The reverse would seem more logical to me -- using some "framework agnostic" (once compiled) Svelte components in an existing app using another technology.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I am importing fullcalendar which is a preact app into my Svelte app. I should have perhaps included that in the question...